# C - pthread_self() getting truncated first 4 bytes?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'm having trouble getting `pthread_equal()` to match stored pthreads. The `pthread_t` I get from `pthread_self()` seems to be truncated by 4 bytes compared to the one I get from `pthread_create()`. Comparisons are in the last code block!

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define QUEUE_SIZE 10
pthread_t *threads_array;
int abc;

void server_loop();
void *a_loop(void *abc);
void printThreadID(pthread_t id);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    server_loop();
    return 0;
}

void server_loop() {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    threads_array = malloc(QUEUE_SIZE * sizeof(pthread_t));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < QUEUE_SIZE; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, a_loop, (void*)&abc) < 0) {
            perror("Thread creation failed");
            fprintf(stderr, "Thread creation #%d failed\n", i);
            printThreadID(thread_id);
            exit(1);
        }

        //... store threadID in array
        fprintf(stderr, "Thread created: ");
        printThreadID(thread_id);

        threads_array[i] = thread_id;

    }
    sleep(5);
}

void *a_loop(void *abc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "@@@@ ");
    printThreadID(pthread_self());

    //... find index of matching pthread_equal(pthread_self(), array[i])

    while (1) {
    }
    return 0;
}


// HELPER METHOD
void printThreadID(pthread_t id){
    size_t i;
    for (i = sizeof(i); i; --i)
        fprintf(stderr, "%02x", *(((unsigned char*) &id) + i - 1));
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}
```

As a result, an attempt to loop through the stored pthreads and compare with pthread_equals fail.
Some comparisons (all ten, every time, get truncated the first 4 bytes):

```
Thread created ID: 00007fda1e402700
self():            000000001e402700
Thread created ID: 00007fda1dc01700
self():            000000001dc01700
Thread created ID: 00007fda1cbff700
self():            000000001cbff700

// Sometimes the zeroes are replaced with ones:
Thread created ID: 00007fda1e402700
self():            ffffffff1e402700
Thread created ID: 00007fda1dc01700
self():            ffffffff1dc01700
Thread created ID: 00007fda1cbff700
self():            ffffffff1cbff700
```

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: `sizeof(i)`. Should that be `sizeof(id)`?

Comment: I tried this change but it still prints out the same results with truncated `pthread_self()` IDs.

Comment: That output does not appear to match that code.

Comment: Also it seems that you ignored some diagnostic of your compiler: your functions are used before they are declared.

Comment: Sorry! I have now updated the lines that I left out.

Comment: Hmmmm. I updated this code so that it fully runs and the `pthread_self()` are getting printed correctly but the implementation I have in my full code still doesn't work out. I figured out a way to avoid what I needed with the IDs for now but if anyone has an idea of what would make cut the id in half like that, I'd be happy to hear. It might have something to do with a bunch of my file linkages but I don't know :/.

Comment: Bytes of pthread_t have no meaning by themselves. The only meaningful query is `pthread_equal`. You say it is failing but your code doesn't show it.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  When compiling, enable all warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  for a start, 1) parameter `argc` not used 2) parameter `argv[]` not used 3) parameter `abc` not used.

Comment: the posted code does not create the output indicated in the question.  Perhaps you could update your question to list the actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function body is the root of the problem:

```
size_t i;
for (i = sizeof(i); i; --i)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%02x", *(((unsigned char*) &id) + i - 1));
}
```

the `pthread_t` does not have the same size as an 'size_t' and the code is using `sizeof(i)` to print the bytes of a `pthread_t`.   suggest:

```
for (i = sizeof(pthread_t); i; --i)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%02x", *(((unsigned char*) &id) + i - 1));
}
```

although a better method, not using a loop,  would be:

```
fprintf( stderr, "%*x", (int)(2*sizeof(pthread_t)), (int)id );
```

caveat: the following code does not compile cleanly.  It outputs a warning message about the unused parameter `abc`

So, with a 'improved' function: `printThreadID()` the program that produced the output is:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define FROM_CREATE (0)
#define FROM_THREAD (1)

#define QUEUE_SIZE (10)
pthread_t *threads_array;
int abc;

void server_loop( void );
void *a_loop(void *abc);
void printThreadID( int, pthread_t );

int main( void )
{
    server_loop();
    return 0;
}

void server_loop()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    if( NULL == (threads_array = malloc(QUEUE_SIZE * sizeof(pthread_t)) ))
    {
        perror( "malloc for thread array failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    for (int i = 0; i < QUEUE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, a_loop, (void*)&abc) < 0)
        {
            perror("Thread creation failed");
            fprintf(stderr, "Thread creation #%d failed\n", i);
            printThreadID(FROM_CREATE, thread_id);
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, pthread_create successful

        //... store threadID in array
        //fprintf(stderr, "Thread created: ");
        printThreadID(FROM_CREATE, thread_id);

        threads_array[i] = thread_id;

    }
    sleep(5);
}

void *a_loop(void *abc)
{
    //fprintf(stderr, "@@@@ ");
    printThreadID( FROM_THREAD, pthread_self());

    //... find index of matching pthread_equal(pthread_self(), array[i])

    while (1)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}


// HELPER METHOD
void printThreadID(int fromThread, pthread_t id)
{
    //size_t i;

    //for (i = sizeof(i); i; --i)
    //{
    //    fprintf(stderr, "%02x", *(((unsigned char*) &id) + i - 1));
    //}
    if( FROM_THREAD == fromThread )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "@@@@ %ld\n", (long int)id );
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "thread created: %ld\n", (long int)id );
    }
    //fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}
```

Here is the output of a typical run of the program, note the exact order of the outputs is depending on which thread wins the race.

```
thread created: 140506339571456
@@@@ 140506339571456
thread created: 140506331178752
thread created: 140506322786048
thread created: 140506314393344
thread created: 140506306000640
thread created: 140506297607936
thread created: 140506289215232
thread created: 140506280822528
thread created: 140506272429824
thread created: 140506264037120
@@@@ 140506331178752
@@@@ 140506297607936
@@@@ 140506322786048
@@@@ 140506289215232
@@@@ 140506280822528
@@@@ 140506314393344
@@@@ 140506272429824
@@@@ 140506264037120
@@@@ 140506306000640
```